# Inverted Vertices / Shader problem?

Tags: vertices, shaders

It seems that the top half of my mesh might be inverted somehow. It has a weird shadow on it. Not sure what this problem is called. I'm new to Blender.
Any advice on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In edit mode select all and press CTRL+N to recalculate normals

Comment: What Johan said. You might want to look at the [page on Normals in the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html?highlight=calculate%20normals), especially the section on Editing near the bottom of the page.